# HTML anchor tag download with CORS

Tags: html, download, cors, anchor

I really don't understand how anchor tag downloads should work, I get that when CORS is not enabled I can not do for example this:

`<a download href="https://www.NotMyHost.com/foo.mp4">Download Video</a>`

but when the `access-control-allow-origin: *` header is present, this should be doable, right?
and if yes, then what is the problem with this tag?

`<a download href="https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/big-buck-bunny-360p.mp4">Download Video</a>`

the source here has the `access-control-allow-origin: *` response header, but it still refuses to download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but when the access-control-allow-origin: * header is present, this should be doable, right?

No. The `download` attribute is not supported on cross-origin requests.

To trigger a download the server hosting the file should set a `Content-Disposition` HTTP response header.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, so I tried including the Content-Disposition header and the download still did not trigger, so is it completely impossible to do cross-origin requests with the download attribute, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is completely impossible.